# How to solve Android Runtime exception on Recycler View Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have app and their one bugs repeating again and again on Recycler view adapter on line number 76 and 42

on 42 line there(this code),

```
itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
```

And on 76 line there(this code),

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

.

Whole Code:

```
package com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Model.Exercises;
import com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.R;
import com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.ViewExercises;

import java.util.List;

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ex_img);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ex_name);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>  {

    private List<Exercises> exercisesList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Exercises> exercisesList, Context context) {
        this.exercisesList = exercisesList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercises,parent,false);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(exercisesList.get(position).getImage_id());
        holder.text.setText(exercisesList.get(position).getName());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(context, ViewExercises.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_id",exercisesList.get(position).getImage_id());
                intent.putExtra("name",exercisesList.get(position).getName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exercisesList.size();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
at com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Adapter.RecyclerViewAdapter$1.onClick
(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:76)

at com.healthy.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Adapter.RecyclerViewHolder.onClick
(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
```

Comment: In the log there's a FATAL EXCEPTION, please copy it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change the code, like this:

```
class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ex_img);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ex_name);

    }

}
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>  {

    private List<Exercises> exercisesList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Exercises> exercisesList, Context context) {
        this.exercisesList = exercisesList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercises,parent,false);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(exercisesList.get(position).getImage_id());
        holder.text.setText(exercisesList.get(position).getName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(context, ViewExercises.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_id",exercisesList.get(position).getImage_id());
                intent.putExtra("name",exercisesList.get(position).getName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exercisesList.size();
    }
}
```

I see you call the listener in two places at once, even though it can be done in one place like through the viewholder